# Syncing .ipynb and .py files?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I created all of my python files (for daily file processing) in Jupyter because it makes it easy for me to view what is going on with the data. Once I finalize something, I create a .py file and then I have Windows Task Scheduler run it for me.

At some point I started to edit these .py files in Pycharm here and there, minor changes or tweaks. Now my original .ipynb files are a bit useless and out of date.

Is there anyway to keep these files synced? Or just a best practice that I should file? Right now I don't really know what is changed, so I am literally going to copy the .py files and paste them into the .ipynb files and overwrite it.

Comment: If you want to see what has changed, you could re-export each notebook to .py, and diff those against the files you already have. There's nothing really designed to sync them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to this question in another tread:

[Synchronizing code between jupyter/iPython notebook script and class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770604/synchronizing-code-between-jupyter-ipython-notebook-script-and-class-methods)

To cut it short you need to use `reload` function from `importlib` module:

```
import babs_visualizations
from importlib import reload
reload(babs_visualizations)
```

Just a little addition: make sure that you are addressing the function in the form of `moldule.function`. If you previously imported function by `from module import funciton` and then reloaded the module the function will not be reloaded!
Cheers.